# Ajax POST error in firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, firefox

I have two PHP files with one posting via ajax to the other one. The post works great in chrome. But it doesnt work in firefox. A debug with firebug shows "POST error" in red color. I am pasting my codes below.

```
Ajax:

var data_val={'user_name' : response.name,
            'user_id' : response.id,
         'user_first' : response.first_name,
         'user_email' : response.email,
       'user_birthday': response.birthday,
       'user_location': response.location.name,
       'user_hometown':response.hometown.name,
     'user_bloodGroup':window.bloodGroup,
      'user_bloodRare':window.user_bloodRare,
       'user_phone_no':window.user_phone,   
         };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",   
                    url: "buddha.php", 
                    data: data_val,})
            });
```

The file into which it is being posted, buddha.php.

```
$name1 = $_POST['user_name'];
$email1 = $_POST['user_email'];
$birthday1=$_POST['user_birthday'];
$location1=$_POST['user_location'];
$hometown1=$_POST['user_hometown'];
$fbbloodgroup=$_POST['user_bloodGroup'];    
$fbuserid=$_POST['user_id'];
$user_phone=$_POST['user_phone_no'];
$user_bloodRare=$_POST['user_bloodRare'];
$user_email=$_POST['user_email'];
```

The above ajax is inside a javascript function,

```
function fetchUserDetail()
```

It is called in a buttonclick as follows.

```
<a class="button_for_me" onclick="checkFacebookLogin()" >Register Me </a>
```

I have to repeat, this works perfectly and pleasantly in chrome. Initially i thought it was the problem of the success alerts shown at he return of the ajax function, but its not.

Comment: Could you give me more information about the error that is displayed on firefox?

Comment: When I use the following function, it prints: "error", "error" and then "an empty string" 

error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(error);
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from your question that "response" is an object returned by FB API call, I would like to say that the problem is with the Facebook API. Sometimes, the user doesn't have value for variables like "Hometown" and "CurrentTown". In that case, the following assign operations in your code would fail.

```
   'user_location': response.location.name,
   'user_hometown':response.hometown.name,
   'user_bloodGroup':window.bloodGroup,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the ajax from:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",   
                url: "buddha.php", 
                data: data_val,})
        });
```

to remove the extra closing tags and `comma` after data_val like

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",   
   url: "buddha.php", 
   data: data_val
});
```

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gf5v0ct/) i created for you with an event binding on the class to trigger the ajax request when clicked.

Comment: It doesnt work. like i said it works perfectly fine in Chrome.